# Error: "Undefined". Getting Undefined while using multer multiple file uploads. Tried most options including restart and npm reinstalling

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman, multer

I am trying to upload multiple images using a get request to update the initial post request that accepts a single upload. Not able to upload multiple images despite using the "files" as suggested in the docs and on here. The (file.filename) comes back undefined for some reason. Also tried changing the base path manually instead of getting it dynamically. Did not work. The images are uploaded to the __dir but shows up as undefined in the database and the postman put console.

```
const express = require("express");
const { Category } = require("../models/category");
const router = express.Router();       //comes with express
const {Product} = require("../models/product")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require("multer");

//MIME TYPE LOOKUP
const FILE_TYPE_MAP = {
    "image/png" : "png",
    "image/jpeg" : "jpeg",
    "image/jpg" : "jpg"
}
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype]
        let uploadError = new Error("invalid Image Format");
        if(isValid){
            uploadError = null;
        }
      cb(uploadError, __dirname + '/public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {//const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype]
        const fileName = file.originalname.split(" ").join("_");
      cb(null,  Date.now() + "-" + fileName + "." + extension )
    }
  })
  
  const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage })

//SINGLE UPLOADS
router.post(`/`, uploadOptions.single("image"), async (req, res)=>{

    let category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category) return res.status(400).send("What the fuck? Invalid category");
    
    const file = req.file;
    if(!file) return res.status(400).send("What the fuck? I need a file");         //compulsary image file upload similar for the category
    const fileName = req.file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/public/uploads/`;
    const product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,//"http://localhost:3000/public/upload/image-213213"
        //images: req.body.images,
        brand: req.body.brand,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured
    })
    product1 = await product.save();
    if(!product1)
    return res.status(500).send("The product cannot be created");

    res.send(product1);
}) 

//MULTIPLE UPLOADS
router.put(
    "/gallery-images/:id",
    uploadOptions.any("images"),
    async (req, res) => {
        if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)){
            res.status(400).send("Invalid product id")
        }
        
        const files = req.files
        let imagePaths = [];
        const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/public/uploads/`;

        if(files){
            files.map(file => {
                imagePaths.push(`${basePath}${files.fileName}`);            })
        }
        
        const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                images: imagePaths
            },
            { new : true}
        )
        
        if(!product)
            return res.status(404).send("The product cannot be updated")

        res.send(product);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

when you were doing the mapping you used **file** as an object and you put **files** to get information from **filename** which is not good. there also it is not **fileName** but rather **filename**.

copy and paste this code you should be fine. next time do a console log of the object for more details it can help you in the future

```
 if(files){
   files.map(file=>{
    //console.log(file)
    imagesPaths.push(`${basePath}${file.filename}`);
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and I also give you a bonus for the extension of the original name which does not fade after this :
*const fileName = file.originalname.split(" ").join("_");*

try that and admire the results

```
const fileName = file.originalname.replace(/(.png|.jpeg|.jpg)/,'')
```